# Which event tells you that the device is successfully started

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I am making an application that auto starts when the phone restarts. I want to run some events when the phone complets its restart. The UiApp is running even before the device finishes his reset cause I configured the app as an auto start app.

What event should I listen too and that starts when the phone completes the reboot, not in between?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing by running before the reboot is complete?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue reading files from the sdCard

Comment: Have you tried using the filesystem listener to find out when the sdcard filesystem is ready?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to know if the system is in startup by using :

```
ApplicationManager.isStartup()
```

You will need to poll this using a timer till it returns false. However it must be borne in mind that this means that the OS has booted and the system is able to run the application. It does not mean that the entire environment for your application to run is set up completely. For example (as noted by Michael) microSD card might not have been mounted, network connectivity might not been established, or some other service on which your application might depend is not yet available. It's up to you to verify they are available before you begin working of your application.

The approach you need to take is:

1. Poll if isStartup returns false (System is not in startup phase)
2. Implement FileSystemListener to check if microSD card is mounted.

Note that mount name for a microSD card is "SDCard".

```
class FileSystemListenerImpl implements FileSystemListener
 {
      final static String SDCARD_NAME ="SDCard/";


    public FileSystemListenerImpl(  )
    {

    }

    public void rootChanged( int state, String rootName )
    {
        if( state ==  FileSystemListener.ROOT_ADDED)
        {

            if( SDCARD_NAME.equals(rootName))
            {
                _isMicroSDReady=true;
                scheduleApplicationStart();
                removeFileSystemListener(this);
            }
        }
        else if( state == FileSystemListener.ROOT_REMOVED)
        {

        }
    }

 }
```