# BlackBerry: Saving file to text file

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I was willing to make a simple application that stores data in a text file according to this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519328/j2me-blackberry-how-to-read-write-text-file) but I am facing a frustrating exception.

This is my code:

```
private boolean saveFile(String fileName, String fileContent) {
         DataOutputStream os = null;
          FileConnection fconn = null;
        try {
        fconn =   (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName,Connector.READ_WRITE);
          if (!fconn.exists())
                fconn.create();
        os=fconn.openDataOutputStream();
        String myString=fileContent;
        os.write(myString.getBytes());
        os.close();
        fconn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Dialog.alert(e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

private String getFileName() {

        return "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/text.dat";

    }
```

This is the exception I get:

```
 net.rim.device.api.io.file.FileIOException: File system error
```

The API says the following:

```
IOException - if the firewall disallows a connection that is not btspp or comm.
```

which I don't know if might be helpful or not.

I am using BlackBerry JRE 4.6.1 and a BlackBerry 8900 Simulator.
Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: which line is throwing the exception? the write?

Comment: What is the value of `fileName` you found while debugging?

Comment: Your requirement is save the text file but in the getFileName() method you are giving "filename.dat". For text file it should be "fileName.txt". and what exception you are getting?

Comment: You can check the value returned by `FileIOException.getErrorCode()`.

Comment: @Tamar `fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName,Connector.READ_WRITE);` is throwing the exception

Comment: @Rupak `file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/text.dat` is the value of `fileName`. This file does not exist. I want to create this new file with the contents of `fileContent`

Comment: @Rupak The error code is 1003.

Comment: I managed to make it work reinserting the SD card. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @George, well done. And 1003 stands for `FileIOException.NO_SUCH_ROOT`, from http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/file/FileIOException.html

Answer (score 1):

Check that your simulator has mounted SDCard. 
If your is autostart you have to wait until system is completely powered up and SDCard is mounted: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267972/which-event-tells-you-that-the-device-is-successfully-started)

And the final - you have to close streams and file connection at the end of failed operation also.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answer is tricky. I kept trying with the same code over and over until I started to think that it was a problem related to the simulator so what I did is, before running the application, I *removed* and *inserted* the SD card using the `Options` item from the Blackberry interface menu and that was it. It worked like charm. I guess it is a bug in the simulator.

Comment: Is your program multithreading? Could be that you are trying to save data in the same file at the same time? Check another JRE or another simulator. I would blame simulator issue as last option from list of possibilities.